# TimePicker showing same time in every TextView

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am working on a module where I have to allow user to set 3 different times in different-different textviews for that I am using TimePicker.

But whenever I select time in TimePicker it showing same time in other two TextViews.

So what could be the reason ?

```
private String textViewTime1, textViewTime2, textViewTime3;
private String mTime1, mTime2, mTime3;

// On clicking Time picker
    public void setTime(View v){
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                this,
                now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                false
        );
        tpd.setThemeDark(false);
        tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
    }

// Obtain time from time picker
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
        if (minute < 10) {
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
        } else {
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        }
        textViewTime1.setText(mTime1);
        textViewTime2.setText(mTime2);
        textViewTime3.setText(mTime3);
    }
```

Comment: `mTime1` `mTime2` and `mTime3` look exactly the same to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Blackbelt lol because they are same

Comment: you need to pass your textview when selecting time and set time in the textview you have passed, here you are setting time in all three textview irrespective of for which you need to set.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Can I have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But whenever I select time in TimePicker it showing same time in other
>   two TextViews.

**Because**, you are setting them the same time!

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
        if (minute < 10) {
            /// Time set to mTime1
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            /// Time set to mTime2 same
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            /// Time set to mTime3 same
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
        } else {
            /// Time set to mTime1
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            /// Time set to mTime2 same
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            /// Time set to mTime3 same
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        }
        textViewTime1.setText(mTime1);
        textViewTime2.setText(mTime2);
        textViewTime3.setText(mTime3);
    }
```

Comment: Ok I got it. Can I have a solution ?

Comment: It depends, what are you trying to achieve? Do you have 3 separate buttons to open the `TimePickerDialog`?

Comment: yes I am using three different-2 textviews to set three different times in that... I am using following code: https://github.com/blanyal/Remindly/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blanyal/remindme/ReminderAddActivity.java

Comment: Then you could just set an int, for example if the `TimePickerDialog` was opened by clicking the first `TextView` you could set the variable's value as `1`. Then in `onTimeSet` you can check. If the value of the int is `1` you can set only the appropriate `TextView`. Similarly for another `TextView` you could set the variable as `2` and then in `onTimeSet` update the respective `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed who should been targeted with the callback so you override all text views. You should use something similar to this:

```
if(view belongs to textViewTime1)
    textViewTime1.setText(mTime1);
if(view belongs to textViewTime2)
    textViewTime2.setText(mTime2);
if(view belongs to textViewTime3)
    textViewTime3.setText(mTime3);
```

Without the information what `view` actual is and how it is wired, I cannot help you with that if condition.

I did a quick review of [`ReminderAddActivity`](https://github.com/blanyal/Remindly/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blanyal/remindme/ReminderAddActivity.java) and [`TimePickerDialog`](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/time/TimePickerDialog.java), you need to apply `TimePickerDialog` to each independent text view. In the end use that control multiple times instead of hacking it together. It won't work this way without rewriting that library you are using.

Comment: I forgot to tap your answer as useful, so i just tapped it :)

Answer (score 0):

// Obtain time from time picker

```
 @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
```

Because every time you set all three time in one method and set it in text view.
Check it carefully and code again.

```
    if (minute < 10) {
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
        } else {
            mTime1 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            mTime2 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            mTime3 = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        }
        textViewTime1.setText(mTime1);
        textViewTime2.setText(mTime2);
        textViewTime3.setText(mTime3);
    }
```